# How can i push changes to my main branch? that's the only one I have

Tags: github, git-merge, git-branch, git-push, git-pull

I have a repository in which I have only main branch. i want to push my new changes to repository but i am facing this issue

[image]

I tried everything. i even deleted my master branch which was 2 commits ahead of main but this error still pops up. I tried to merge these two branches but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1: Run a `git pull --rebase`
2: Try committing again (`git commit -a`)
3: Try pushing again `git push -f`

The `-f` flag tells it to force a push, overriding the remote code with your local code. Pulling and committing is so that if you had made changes on the remote, they are synced with your current (local) branch (without the `--rebase` flag, the pull will fail, which is what happened when you pulled).